# While 'id_genero' does exist, the Error Code: 1072. Key column 'id_genero' doesn't exist in table comes out

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE genero (
    id_genero int NOT NULL,
    descripcion_genero varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (id_genero)
);

CREATE TABLE pegi (
    id_pegi int NOT NULL,
    descripcion_pegi varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (id_pegi)
);

CREATE TABLE serie (
    id_serie int NOT NULL,
    titulo varchar(255),
    sinopsis varchar(255),
    fecha DATE,
    idioma varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (id_serie),
    CONSTRAINT fk_id_genero FOREIGN KEY (id_genero)
    REFERENCES genero(id_genero),
    CONSTRAINT fk_id_pegi FOREIGN KEY (id_pegi)
    REFERENCES pegi(id_pegi)
);
```

While 'id_genero' does exist, the error code: 1072 comes out. The table pegi and genero are created successfully, but series can't be created.

Answer (score 1):

Can you show us the exact error message that you are receiving?

From the question, I can assume that you are missing these two columns inside the table series: id_genero AND id_pegi

```
CREATE TABLE genero (
    id_genero int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    descripcion_genero varchar(255)
);

CREATE TABLE pegi (
        id_pegi int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        descripcion_pegi varchar(255)
    );
    
    CREATE TABLE serie (
        id_serie int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        titulo varchar(255),
        sinopsis varchar(255),
        fecha DATE,
        idioma varchar(255),
        id_genero int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES genero(id_genero),
        id_pegi int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES pegi(id_pegi)
    );
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm completely new to sql. In order to use     PRIMARY KEY (id_serie),
 CONSTRAINT fk_id_genero FOREIGN KEY (id_genero) you should define id_genero first?

Comment: No, in order to use fk_id_genero you must create column id_genero inside serie table, and same for other fk, id_pegi. So you will have same columns in both tables that are refencing each other.

Comment: @lzy917 - I have edited the answer, check out, it will be more clear to you.